# expo-location not reversing geocode properly?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I am simply trying to get my user's location based on their permission, I get the location quite alright. I then try to reverse the geocode using the same expo-location I always get the same results:

```js
Object {
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "country": "United States",
  "district": "Union Square",
  "isoCountryCode": "US",
  "name": "1 Stockton St",
  "postalCode": "94108",
  "region": "CA",
  "street": "Stockton St",
  "streetNumber": "1",
  "subregion": "San Francisco County",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
}
```

for the record, the location also returns the same location longitude and latitude even when I change location. I don't know what the cause of this is. I have tested it with both ios and android and it turns out the same.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Device from 'expo-device';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [refreshLocation, setRefreshLocation] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location);
        console.log(location.coords.latitude);
        console.log(location.coords.longitude);

        // Add a delay before making the geocoding request
        setTimeout(async () => {
          let geocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          });

          if (geocode.length > 0) {
            const address = geocode[0];
            // Use the address properties as needed
            // console.log('geocode: ' + JSON.stringify(geocode));
            setAddress(address);
          }
        }, 1000); // Adjust the delay time as needed
      } catch (error) {
        setErrorMsg("Error retrieving location: " + error.message);
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [refreshLocation]);

  const refreshFlag = () => setRefreshLocation((prevState) => !prevState);

  return { refreshFlag, isLoading, address, errorMsg };
};

export default useLocation;
```